# Type guard in function doens't work through another function

Tags: typescript

```js
let value: number | null = 1;

function isNotNull(arg: number | null) {
  return arg !== null;
}
function feature() {
  if (isNotNull(value)) {
    console.log('passed');
    **value;**
  }
}
```

For the * marked part, I assumed it would be inferred to be number but it seems like type guard inside deeper function doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in an actual [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to inform the TypeScript compiler of the fact that your `isNotNull()` function asserts that the argument is a number:

```
const value: number | null = 1;

function isNotNull(arg: number | null): arg is number {
  return arg !== null;
}

function feature() {
  if (isNotNull(value)) {
    console.log('passed: ' + value); // inferred as number
  }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that there isn't any benefit in having an `isNotNull` function when you can just inline `value !== null`.